# Ubuntu 14.04: How to let printk print to a specific file

Tags: linux, kernel

In earlier version of Ubuntu, this can be done by modifying the /etc/syslog.conf file. But now in Ubuntu 14.04, this file is not missing. How can I let printk print to a specific file?

Comment: Do you mean 16.04? By earlier version, which one do you mean?

Comment: 12.04 is what I used to use.